# The usage of "increased"

Tags: word-meaning

I wrote:

> An increased bending in a pallet car can stop the conveyor.

Here by "increased" I mean a bending which is ...mmmm.. beyond a specific limit, exceeding a limit (something like overload, or **excess** (maybe I should use excess!)). I don't know if it means what I purpose or not! to me "increased" needs a reference point.

I searched for the meaning of "increased" but didn't find much in dictionaries. [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/increase_1) has an example

> an increased incidence of childhood leukaemia

but don't know if it matches my meaning.

The question is does increased means something like excess?, if not what it means?

Comment: In what dictionary did you fail to find a definition of the verb _increase?_

Comment: @P.E.Dant for example in http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/increase?q=increased or in http://www.ldoceonline.com/search/?q=increased

Comment: The definition there is _Become or make greater in size, amount, or degree._ "Increased" is the _participle_ of the verb and is used as an adjective in your sentence. What about that definition do you not understand?

Comment: it is unclear from your question exactly what it is you're trying to learn. What is your question?

Comment: @Ahmad Your [link to *Longman*](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/increase_1) does not work for me (USA). It says: Impossible to contact server.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I added more information, but actually I don't get the meaning of "increased" in this sentence and if it means what I purpose or not. to me it should mean, *exceeding a limit*, it needs a reference point to count it as an *increased*

Comment: _Increaaed_ does not mean _exceeding a limit._ Again: what is your question? What is it that you want to express? There is no question in your question!

Comment: "Bending beyond a specified limit can stop the conveyor." "Bending that exceeds a specified limit can stop the conveyor."

Comment: @P.E.Dant maybe *excess* is what I look for, then the question is *does increased means excess?, if not what it means?*

Comment: See my previous comment. "Exceed" is the verb you need here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant thanks, I wrote *Bending that exceeds a specified limit can stop the conveyor; therefore, an early and precise diagnosis is required*, as I checked **diagnosis** is used more for diseases, did I used it correctly here?

Comment: Perfect! _Diagnosis_ is not only a medical term. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Does *increased* means something like *excess*?

It does not. The word *[increased](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/increased)* means "greater in size, amount, or degree", whereas *[excess](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/excess_2)* means "more than is usual or necessary". An increased value may or may not exceed the allowed limit.

So, the sentence you proposed in the question, *An increased bending in a pallet car can stop the conveyor*, and another sentence you proposed in a comment, *Bending that exceeds a specified limit can stop the conveyor; therefore, an early and precise diagnosis is required*, do not have the same meaning.

The phrase *bending that exceeds a specified limit* is correct, considering your intended meaning.
In case you want something more concise, *[overbending](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overbending)* is a possible alternative.